# Leer n datos y mostrarlos en pantalla c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en consola c# en donde se deben de leer n vendedores, de cada vendedor interesa el nombre, el precio de cada auto vendido y salario mínimo. El sueldo del vendedor será de la siguiente manera: salario mínimo mas $1000 por cada auto vendido mas el 2% del valor de los autos vendidos. Al finalizar la lectura de los vendedores deberá imprimirse un reporte por vendedor:

```
Nombre: xxxxx
Sueldo: $99999.00
```

Después de procesar todos los vendedores mostrar el siguiente reporte:

```
Total de vendedores: 99
Nomina: $99999.99
```

Hasta el momento tengo esto:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   char resp = 's';
   double nomina = 0.0, sueldo = 0.0, auto1 = 0.0, auto2 = 0.0, auto3 = 0.0, autos = 0.0, salario = 0.0;
   int vendedores = 0, comision = 0;
   string vendedor = "";

   do
   {
       Console.Write("Nombre del vendedor: ");
       vendedor = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.Write("Precio Auto 1: ");
       auto1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.Write("Precio Auto 2: ");
       auto2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.Write("Precio Auto 3: ");
       auto3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.Write("Salario Minimo: ");
       salario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
       autos = auto1 + auto2 + auto3;

       comision = 0;

       if (auto1 > 0)
            comision += 1000;

       if (auto2 > 0)
            comision += 1000;

       if (auto3 > 0)
            comision += 1000;

       sueldo = salario + comision + (autos * 0.02);
       vendedores++;
       nomina += sueldo;

       Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + vendedor);
       Console.WriteLine("Sueldo: $" + sueldo.ToString(".00"));
                
       Console.Write("¿Deseas registrar otro vendedor (s/n)? ");
       resp = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    } while (resp == 's');

    Console.WriteLine("Total de vendedores: " + vendedores);
    Console.WriteLine("Nomina: $" + nomina.ToString(".00"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Me falta mostrar el reporte por cada vendedor al finalizar la lectura de datos, la verdad ahí estoy perdido, algo a considerar para este ejercicio es que no se pueden usar arreglos.

Agradecería mucho que me pudieran orientar.

Answer (score 0):

Por el planteamiento del problema, parece un ejercicio enfocado a la búsqueda de una solución orientada a objetos. Si tus requisitos prohíben el uso de arreglos o arrays pero no colecciones de tipo List, una solución posible es crear una clase Vendedor que cree el modelo o "blueprint" de un vendedor, declarar una colección de este tipo de objetos y llenarla en cada iteración con objetos de tipo Vendedor, para iterar finalmente por la colección y mostrar su información:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Vendedor
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public double SalarioMinimo { get; set; }
    public double PrecioAuto1 { get; set; }
    public double PrecioAuto2 { get; set; }
    public double PrecioAuto3 { get; set; }
    public double Comision { get; set; }
    public double Sueldo { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char resp = 's';
        double nomina = 0.0;
        int vendedores = 0;

        List<Vendedor> vendedoresLista = new List<Vendedor>();

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Nombre del vendedor: ");
            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 1: ");
            double precioAuto1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 2: ");
            double precioAuto2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 3: ");
            double precioAuto3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Salario Minimo: ");
            double salarioMinimo = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            double comision = 0.0;

            if (precioAuto1 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            if (precioAuto2 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            if (precioAuto3 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            double sueldo = salarioMinimo + comision + ((precioAuto1 + precioAuto2 + precioAuto3) * 0.02);

            Vendedor v = new Vendedor();
            v.Nombre = nombre;
            v.SalarioMinimo = salarioMinimo;
            v.PrecioAuto1 = precioAuto1;
            v.PrecioAuto2 = precioAuto2;
            v.PrecioAuto3 = precioAuto3;
            v.Comision = comision;
            v.Sueldo = sueldo;
            
            vendedoresLista.Add(v);

            vendedores++;
            nomina += sueldo;

            // Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + nombre);
            // Console.WriteLine("Sueldo: $" + sueldo.ToString(".00"));

            Console.Write("¿Deseas registrar otro vendedor (s/n)? ");
            resp = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (resp == 's');

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Reporte individual de cada vendedor:");
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Vendedor v in vendedoresLista)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + v.Nombre);
            Console.WriteLine("Sueldo: $" + v.Sueldo.ToString(".00"));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Reporte global de la empresa:");
        Console.WriteLine("Número total de vendedores: " + vendedores);
        Console.WriteLine("Monto total de las nóminas: $" + nomina.ToString(".00"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Te he dejado un Replit con la solución [aquí](https://replit.com/@alejandroMAD/CSharpVendedoresOOP#main.cs).

Comment: Añadir que ya que usas clases puedes sobrescribir la función toSting con su parte del reporte. de forma que solo tendras dentro del for `Console.WriteLine(v.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

En este caso tienes dos opciones usar una lista de classes o puedes concatenar el reporte en una variable string.
Como ya publicaron una de lista te doy ejemplo para el de string, tiene que ir sumando los vendedores con su parte del reporte (para saltos de línea usa el carácter \n)finalmente haces console.write o writeline de la variable.

Ejemplo:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char resp = 's';
        double nomina = 0.0, sueldo = 0.0, auto1 = 0.0, auto2 = 0.0, auto3 = 0.0, autos = 0.0, salario = 0.0;
        int vendedores = 0, comision = 0;
        string vendedor = "";
        string reporte = ""; // inicalizar string reporte con cadena vacia para poder usar += desde el principio

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Nombre del vendedor: ");
            vendedor = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 1: ");
            auto1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 2: ");
            auto2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Precio Auto 3: ");
            auto3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Salario Minimo: ");
            salario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            autos = auto1 + auto2 + auto3;

            comision = 0;

            if (auto1 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            if (auto2 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            if (auto3 > 0)
                comision += 1000;

            sueldo = salario + comision + (autos * 0.02);
            vendedores++;
            nomina += sueldo;

            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + vendedor);
            Console.WriteLine("Sueldo: $" + sueldo.ToString(".00"));
            //assignar estructura reporte
            reporte += "Vendedor:" + vendedor + "\n";
            reporte += " Precio Auto 1:" + auto1 + "\n";
            reporte += " Precio Auto 2:" + auto2 + "\n";
            reporte += " Precio Auto 3:" + auto3 + "\n";
            reporte += " Salario Minimo:" + salario + "\n";
            reporte += " Num de autos:" + autos + "\n";
            reporte += " Comision:" + comision + "\n";
            reporte += " Sueldo:" + sueldo + "\n\n";
        
            Console.Write("¿Deseas registrar otro vendedor (s/n)? ");
            resp = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (resp == 's');

        Console.WriteLine("Total de vendedores: " + vendedores);
        Console.WriteLine("Nomina: $" + nomina.ToString(".00"));
        //imprimir reporte
        Console.WriteLine("------REPORTE------");
        Console.WriteLine(reporte);
        Console.ReadKey();






    }
```

El resultado (con números y nombre random):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: PD: hay otra usando hilos y retrasándolos, pero creo que no vale la pena para este tipo de ejercicio.